# Intermittent Null Reference Errors When Accessing Stored Proc Output Parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, ado.net

I have some code that accesses a stored procedure, using a datareader, that returns a few output parameters and a result set as well. The datareader is created with a using block.

The problem is that I *sometimes* get a "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object" when trying to access the output parameters. I know that this error is normally received if the datareader is not closed when trying to access the output parameters. However, because the datareader is accessed in a using block and the code that accesses the output parameters is outside the using block, the parameters should never be null.

How is this possible?

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = "stored proc";

CommandBehavior commandBehavior = new CommandBehavior();

using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader(commandBehavior))
{
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        //access record values
    }
}

var param1 = command.Parameters["firstParam"].Value;  //<-- null reference error here
```

I have omitted some code for brevity.

The code and SQL server run on VM's.

Other relevant facts: C# .Net Framework 4.0, SQL Server 2012

Comment: Yes, I am accessing the value elsewhere.

Comment: Can you show your sproc, please? I Think I have seen an error like this, if you get a deadlock.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to show the exact sproc. However, the sproc does not do any updates (just selects) and it uses snapshot isolation level. I will try to simulate a deadlock and see if this simulates the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to track the problem by running SQL profiler on the DB. I was lucky to catch an error. Checking the SQL logs showed that there was a deadlock. However, the error was not being received by the application. In order to simulate the error try the following stored procedure (copied from @Shakti):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
@parm1 varchar(100),
@parm2 Varchar(200) = '' OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 AS parm1
    SELECT * FROM some_table
    SELECT @parm2 = 'Shakti Singh' 
    THROW 1,'Deadlock Error!',1   --error number not important, any error here will simulate the problem, in my case a deadlock
END
```

In the application, you will be able to read through the data reader without any errors, but you will not be able to access the output params. However, if you throw the error before the SELECT *, the application will get the error but you will obviously not be able to read through the data reader.

Comment: The actual problem is that you may not read output parameters before closing the datareader. "The Close method fills in the values for output parameters" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close?view=netframework-4.8. So the deadlock was a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your code looks correct which leads me to consider possible reasons that may exist in your omitted code or in the stored procedure. My apologies if you've already checked these out.

1. Is the SQL stored procedure returning a null for the parameter value for some queries?
2. Of the code omitted, did any of it change the commandBehavior - if the behaviour is set to `CloseConnection`, then there is your reason.

   BTW. the creation and use of `commandBahavior()` in your could is unnecessary - what you have is your code is exactly the same as `reader = command.ExecuteReader()`
3. Did you initialise the `command.Parameters["firstParam"]` prior to `command.ExecuteReader()` as set it up with direction=output and of the correct type.
4. Are you returning multiple recordsets for some runs of the stored procedure? I believe parameters get disrupted on such cases although I've never experience it personally to know for certain

Comment: 1. I have checked this. I have code to handle a return value of DBNull. I have also simulated returning null values.
2. The commandBehaviour is set to closeConnection. But this does not affect the reading of the output params.
3. Yes, the output param is initialised correctly.
4. I have checked for the return of multiple recordsets. This is not an issue.
As mentioned, the problem is intermittent, so there is some external factor affecting the result. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: The intermitant nature is certainly baffling.  It suggests that the parameters is being lost to the garbage collector but I'm not wholly convinced.   Do you have a stack trace from an error.  I'm initially wondering on which object the null is detected:  cmd, parameters, or parameters["<item>"].   If the cause is in somewhere within sql.data classes (connection or data transfer, etc) I'd expect to see an exception long before the .value accessor. Nevertheless, are you able to put a trace on sql (sql profiler) to capture sql exceptions or warnings.

Comment: The null is detected on parameters["<item>"]. I have simulated the exact error (and stack trace) by taking the datareader instantiation out of a using block (in effect not closing the reader before accessing the output param). I tend to agree with your suggestion that the error is somewhere in the connection or data transfer - the problem is simulating it.

Comment: The simulated failure before closing the reader suggests to me that you did not reach the end of the resultset. To my knowledge, the parameters are only processed after *all* of the resultset have completed i.e. the trailing part of the sql entire data stream. In my mind - righly or wrongly - the closing of the reader only 'releases' the parameters to the client.  Having said that, I would have thought an exception (a timeout most likely) would have occured at some point.  As I pointed out in previously, its almost as if sql is sending more than 1 resultset and your only reading the first.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code, I have tested it is working fine.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Test",con);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parm1", "Hi");
            command.Parameters.Add("@parm2",SqlDbType.VarChar,500).Value = "";
            command.Parameters["@parm2"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            //CommandBehavior commandBehavior = new CommandBehavior();
            var parm2 = "";
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //access record values
                }
                reader.Close();
                parm2 = Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["@parm2"].Value);
            }
```

**SP :**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
@parm1 varchar(100),
@parm2 Varchar(200) = '' OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 AS parm1
    SELECT @parm2 = 'Shakti Singh'
END
```

Comment: I have tried similar code. The problem is that the error occurs intermittently.  If there was a problem with the code, the error would always occur.

Comment: Can you check firstParam output parameter value from SQL wherever you got NULL reference error in C#, I think in case of error you must be getting some weird data from database.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your code is correct and you just need to handle null on the line you mentioned, please try to replace that line with following code .

```
var param1 = Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["firstParam"].Value);
```

Comment: Please see comment above. Null is being handled.

Answer (score 0):

use 'as' string keyword

```
command.Parameters["@parm2"].Value as string
```